# Handling collisions with objects that use vector of unique pointers

Tags: c++, c++11, sfml

```
 #pragma once
#include "Entity.h"
#include <iostream>

class Projectile : public Entity
{
public:
    Projectile() {}

    Projectile(float x, float y) {
        load("Graphics/Projectile.png");
        m_sprite.setPosition(x, y);
        m_speed = 400;
    }
};

#pragma once

#include "Entity.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Projectile.h"

enum class Color {
    red, 
    yellow, 
    brown,
    blue
};

class Enemy : public Entity
{
public:
    Enemy(const Color& c, const sf::Vector2f& pos) {
        switch (c) {
            case Color::blue:
            {
                load("Graphics/blueEnemy.png");
            }
            break;
            case Color::red:
            {
                load("Graphics/redEnemy.png");
            }
            break;
            case Color::yellow:
            {
                load("Graphics/yellowEnemy.png");
            }
            break;
            case Color::brown:
            {
                load("Graphics/brownEnemy.png");
            }
            break;
        }
        setPos(pos);
        m_speed = 100; 
    }
};



  #pragma once
    #include "Entity.h"
    #include "Projectile.h"
    #include <vector>

class Spaceship : public Entity 
{
public:
    Spaceship();
    void move(float);
    void shoot(float);
    void update(float);
    void draw(sf::RenderWindow*) override;
private:
    bool wasSpacePressed; 
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Projectile>> m_projectiles; 
    sf::Clock m_clock; 
};


class EnemyFleet : public Entity
{
public:
    EnemyFleet();
    ~EnemyFleet();
    void move(float);
    bool isEnemyBottom() const; 
    bool isLeftMost() const;
    bool isRightMost() const;
    void moveX(float);
    void moveDown();
    void update(float);
    void draw(sf::RenderWindow*) override;

private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Enemy>> m_enemyFleet; 
    bool m_leftToRight; //motion of the enemyfleet
    float m_speedModifier;
};
```

I want to be able to delete a projectile and enemy when they collide with each other, but I'm not sure how to do this since unique_ptr cannot be copied into any parameter in some collision manager class bc it has exclusive ownership. Is unique_ptr still something i should use bc i dont have to call delete (like if its a raw ptr)?

Comment: `unique_ptr` can be passed by `const reference` or `const raw pointer`, or can be moved.

Comment: but if im deleting it in the vector im passing a vector and also it cant be const since im affecting the unique objects inside the vector

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can't copy `unique_ptr`, but you can copy or get reference from object that `unique_ptr` points to (`Projectile` and `Enemy`).

```
//Example

bool collision_manager::is_collision(Projectile & pr, Enemy & en) {
    if (pr.position() == en.position()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false
}

// similar for other objects that contain vector of unique_ptr
Projectile & Spaceship::get_Projectile(size_t num) {
    if(num < m_projectiles.length()) {
        return *projectiles.at(num);
    }
    throw std::invalid_argument("some alert info");
}
```

- Instead of copying you can also use `std::move(unique_ptr...)`.

Comment: Interesting but deleting the location of the unique_ptr in the vector will be tough

Comment: Well not tough but i suppose i'd have to mark some private isAlive member in enemy and projectile, then have some kind of garbage collection function erase all of the objects marked as not alive. Seems a little much i guess, is there a better way im not thinking of?

Comment: I don't know details about your project, but your probably have something similar to main_loop that have manager_collision in and access to other objects. 
To delete object you simply  need to use ```vector.erase(pos_in_vector)``` when collision is detected, this call deleter in unique_ptr that call destructor of the pointing object.

Comment: Oh ok makes sense thanks. Sorry one final question would be why would I only return one projectile at a time in the getter fn? how would that work? Wouldnt it make more sense to do a vector of pointers to all the projectile objects?

Comment: If you have function that getting reference to one projectile, you can easily write a loop that will pass all projectiles.
Organize the code for small functions that do the basic things is good practice.

Comment: oh right sorry this is my first time writing a collision manager so i forgot i should have both objects as members in it.